# What's a good non-networked example of the new C# Async feature?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0, async-await

Microsoft just announced the [new C# Async feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx). Every example I've seen so far is about asynchronously downloading something from HTTP. Surely there are other important async things?

Suppose I'm not writing a new RSS client or Twitter app. What's interesting about C# Async for me?

**Edit** I had an Aha! moment while watching [Anders' PDC session](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/1b127a7d-300e-4385-af8e-ac747fee677a/). In the past I have worked on programs that used "watcher" threads. These threads sit  waiting for something to happen, like watching for a file to change. They aren't doing work, they're just idle, and notify the main thread when something happens. These threads could be replaced with await/async code in the new model.

Comment: Or to pose the question more generally, when is async useful?  Almost any general async example should have relevance to what's been shown in C# 5.

Comment: When you say "non-networked" do you really mean "non-I/O"? Because really all I/O could block.

Comment: +1 Suppose I am deaing with data flows from the netwok but through 3d-party terminal and I have no clue what is inside of the terminal or how it is getting data from net, I am just using its dll and have all the data in my program appearing asynchronously as a magic. No need to know anything about network. But I need to know async/await

Answer (score 25):

Ooh, this sounds interesting.  I'm not playing with the CTP just yet, just reviewing the whitepaper.  After seeing [Anders Hejlsberg's talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-Async) about it, I think I can see how it could prove useful.

As I understand, async makes writing asynchronous calls easier to read and implement.  Very much in the same way writing iterators is easier right now (as opposed to writing out the functionality by hand).  This is essential blocking processes since no useful work can be done, until it is unblocked.  If you were downloading a file, you cannot do anything useful until you get that file letting the thread go to waste.  Consider how one would call a function which you know will block for an undetermined length and returns some result, then process it (e.g., store the results in a file).  How would you write that?  Here's a simple example:

```
static object DoSomeBlockingOperation(object args)
{
    // block for 5 minutes
    Thread.Sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);

    return args;
}

static void ProcessTheResult(object result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

static void CalculateAndProcess(object args)
{
    // let's calculate! (synchronously)
    object result = DoSomeBlockingOperation(args);

    // let's process!
    ProcessTheResult(result);
}
```

Ok good, we have it implemented.  But wait, the calculation takes minutes to complete.  What if we wanted to have an interactive application and do other things while the calculation took place (such as rendering the UI)?  This is no good, since we called the function synchronously and we have to wait for it to finish effectively freezing the application since the thread is waiting to be unblocked.

Answer, call the function expensive function asynchronously.  That way we're not bound to waiting for the blocking operation to complete.  But how do we do that?  We'd call the function asynchronously and register a callback function to be called when unblocked so we may process the result.

```
static void CalculateAndProcessAsyncOld(object args)
{
    // obtain a delegate to call asynchronously
    Func<object, object> calculate = DoSomeBlockingOperation;

    // define the callback when the call completes so we can process afterwards
    AsyncCallback cb = ar =>
        {
            Func<object, object> calc = (Func<object, object>)ar.AsyncState;
            object result = calc.EndInvoke(ar);

            // let's process!
            ProcessTheResult(result);
        };

    // let's calculate! (asynchronously)
    calculate.BeginInvoke(args, cb, calculate);
}
```

- Note: Sure we could start another thread to do this but that would mean we're spawning a thread that just sits there waiting to be unblocked, then do some useful work.  That would be a waste.

Now the call is asynchronous and we don't have to worry about waiting for the calculation to finish and process, it's done asynchronously.  It will finish when it can.  An alternative to calling code asynchronously directly, you could use a Task:

```
static void CalculateAndProcessAsyncTask(object args)
{
    // create a task
    Task<object> task = new Task<object>(DoSomeBlockingOperation, args);

    // define the callback when the call completes so we can process afterwards
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // let's process!
            ProcessTheResult(t.Result);
        });

    // let's calculate! (asynchronously)
    task.Start();
}
```

Now we called our function asynchronously.  But what did it take to get it that way?  First of all, we needed the delegate/task to be able to call it asynchronously, we needed a callback function to be able to process the results, then call the function.  We've turned a two line function call to much more just to call something asynchronously.  Not only that, the logic in the code has gotten more complex then it was or could be.  Although using a task helped simplify the process, we still needed to do stuff to make it happen.  We just want to run asynchronously then process the result.  Why can't we just do that?  Well now we can:

```
// need to have an asynchronous version
static async Task<object> DoSomeBlockingOperationAsync(object args)
{
    //it is my understanding that async will take this method and convert it to a task automatically
    return DoSomeBlockingOperation(args);
}

static async void CalculateAndProcessAsyncNew(object args)
{
    // let's calculate! (asynchronously)
    object result = await DoSomeBlockingOperationAsync(args);

    // let's process!
    ProcessTheResult(result);
}
```

Now this was a very simplified example with simple operations (calculate, process).  Imagine if each operation couldn't conveniently be put into a separate function but instead have hundreds of lines of code.  That's a lot of added complexity just to gain the benefit of asynchronous calling.

---

Another practical example used in the whitepaper is using it on UI apps.  Modified to use the above example:

```
private async void doCalculation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    doCalculation.IsEnabled = false;
    await DoSomeBlockingOperationAsync(GetArgs());
    doCalculation.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

If you've done any UI programming (be it WinForms or WPF) and attempted to call an expensive function within a handler, you'll know this is handy.  Using a background worker for this wouldn't be that much helpful since the background thread will be sitting there waiting until it can work.

---

Suppose you had a way to control some external device, let's say a printer.  And you wanted to restart the device after a failure.  Naturally it will take some time for the printer to start up and be ready for operation.  You might have to account for the restart not helping and attempt to restart again.  You have no choice but to wait for it.  Not if you did it asynchronously.

```
static async void RestartPrinter()
{
    Printer printer = GetPrinter();
    do
    {
        printer.Restart();

        printer = await printer.WaitUntilReadyAsync();

    } while (printer.HasFailed);
}
```

Imagine writing the loop without async.

---

One last example I have.  Imagine if you had to do multiple blocking operations in a function and wanted to call asynchronously.  What would you prefer?

```
static void DoOperationsAsyncOld()
{
    Task op1 = new Task(DoOperation1Async);
    op1.ContinueWith(t1 =>
    {
        Task op2 = new Task(DoOperation2Async);
        op2.ContinueWith(t2 =>
        {
            Task op3 = new Task(DoOperation3Async);
            op3.ContinueWith(t3 =>
            {
                DoQuickOperation();
            }
            op3.Start();
        }
        op2.Start();
    }
    op1.Start();
}

static async void DoOperationsAsyncNew()
{
    await DoOperation1Async();

    await DoOperation2Async();

    await DoOperation3Async();

    DoQuickOperation();
}
```

Read the [whitepaper](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204844), it actually has a lot of practical examples like writing parallel tasks and others.

I can't wait to start playing with this either in the CTP or when .NET 5.0 finally makes it out.

Comment: I'm not sure the syntax is 100% sound using async but you get the idea.

Comment: In the case of a UI, I think a `BackgroundWorker` would be a better choice then using `async` and `await`.

Comment: Wrong. `async` does NOT start any threads, so your DoSomeVeryExpensiveCalculation() will NOT be executed in the background. Remember that `async` is for operations that run only for a short time and then `await` something. If you want to run long CPU-intensive operation in the background, you need to explicitly do that in the background:

static Task<object> DoSomeVeryExpensiveCalculationAsync(object args)
{
    return Task.CreateNew(() => DoSomeVeryExpensiveCalculation(args));
}

Comment: The new language support is nice because it allows you to easily *compose* asynchronous operations. It's for composition, not for auto-parallelizing. (your doCalculation_Click is a good example of composition)

Comment: @Daniel: I've updated the answer.  I have to admit, I don't use asynchronous calls often nowadays except when writing networking code.  Hopefully it should be satisfactory now.

Answer (score 17):

The main scenarios are any scenario that involves *high latency*. That is, lots of time between "ask for a result" and "obtain a result". Network requests are the most obvious example of high latency scenarios, followed closely by I/O in general, and then by lengthy computations that are CPU bound on another core.

However, there are potentially other scenarios that this technology will mesh nicely with. For example, consider scripting the logic of a FPS game. Suppose you have a button click event handler. When the player clicks the button you want to play a siren for two seconds to alert the enemies, and then open the door for ten seconds. Wouldn't it be nice to say something like:

```
button.Disable();
await siren.Activate(); 
await Delay(2000);
await siren.Deactivate();
await door.Open();
await Delay(10000);
await door.Close();
await Delay(1000);
button.Enable();
```

Each task gets queued up on the UI thread, so nothing blocks, and each one resumes the click handler at the right point after its job is finished.

Answer (score 9):

I've found another nice use-case for this today: you can await user interaction.

For example, if one form has a button that opens another form:

```
Form toolWindow;
async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (toolWindow != null) {
     toolWindow.Focus();
  } else {
     toolWindow = new Form();
     toolWindow.Show();
     await toolWindow.OnClosed();
     toolWindow = null;
  }
}
```

Granted, this isn't really any simpler than

```
toolWindow.Closed += delegate { toolWindow = null; }
```

But I think it nicely demonstrates what `await` can do. And once the code in the event handler is non-trivial, `await` make programming much easier. Think about the user having to click a sequence of buttons:

```
async void ButtonSeries()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Text = i.ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(b);
    await b.OnClick();
    this.Controls.Remove(b);
  }
}
```

Sure, you could do this with normal event handlers, but it would require you to take apart the loop and convert it into something much harder to understand.

Remember that `await` can be used with anything that gets completed at some point in the future. Here's the extension method Button.OnClick() to make the above work:

```
public static AwaitableEvent OnClick(this Button button)
{
    return new AwaitableEvent(h => button.Click += h, h => button.Click -= h);
}
sealed class AwaitableEvent
{
    Action<EventHandler> register, deregister;
    public AwaitableEvent(Action<EventHandler> register, Action<EventHandler> deregister)
    {
        this.register = register;
        this.deregister = deregister;
    }
    public EventAwaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return new EventAwaiter(this);
    }
}
sealed class EventAwaiter
{
    AwaitableEvent e;
    public EventAwaiter(AwaitableEvent e) { this.e = e; }

    Action callback;

    public bool BeginAwait(Action callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        e.register(Handler);
        return true;
    }
    public void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        callback();
    }
    public void EndAwait()
    {
        e.deregister(Handler);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to add the `GetAwaiter()` method directly to `EventHandler` (allowing `await button.Click;`) because then the method wouldn't know how to register/deregister that event.
It's a bit of boilerplate, but the AwaitableEvent class can be re-used for all events (not just UI). And with a minor modification and adding some generics, you could allow retrieving the EventArgs:

```
MouseEventArgs e = await button.OnMouseDown();
```

I could see this being useful with some more complex UI gestures (drag'n'drop, mouse gestures, ...) - though you'd have to add support for cancelling the current gesture.

Answer (score 4):

There are some samples and demos in the CTP that don't use the Net, and even some that don't do any I/O.

And it does apply to all  multithreaded / parallel problem areas (that already exist).

Async and Await are a new (easier) way of structuring all parallel code, be it CPU-bound or I/O bound. The biggest improvement is in areas where before C#5 you had to use the APM (IAsyncResult) model, or the event model (BackgroundWorker, WebClient). I think that is why those examples lead the parade now.

Answer (score 3):

A GUI clock is a good example; say you want to draw a clock, that updates the time shown every second.  Conceptually, you want to write

```
 while true do
    sleep for 1 second
    display the new time on the clock
```

and with `await` (or with F# async) to asynchronously sleep, you can write this code to run on the UI thread in a non-blocking fashion.

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/f-async-on-the-client-side/

Answer (score 2):

The `async` extensions are useful in some cases when you have an *asynchronous operation.* An asynchronous operation has a definite *start* and *completion.* When asynchronous operations complete, they may have a result or an error. (Cancellation is treated as a special kind of error).

Asynchronous operations are useful in three situations (broadly speaking):

- Keeping your UI responsive. Any time you have a long-running operation (whether CPU-bound or I/O-bound), make it asynchronous.
- Scaling your servers. Using asynchronous operations judiciously on the server side may help your severs to scale. e.g., asynchronous ASP.NET pages may make use of `async` operations. However, this is [not always a win;](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/11/14/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous.aspx) you need to evaluate your scalability bottlenecks first.
- Providing a clean asynchronous API in a library or shared code. `async` is excellent for reusability.

As you begin to adopt the `async` way of doing things, you'll find the third situation becoming more common. `async` code works best with other `async` code, so asynchronous code kind of "grows" through the codebase.

There are a couple of types of concurrency where `async` is *not* the best tool:

- Parallelization. A parallel algorithm may use many cores (CPUs, GPUs, computers) to solve a problem more quickly.
- Asynchronous events. Asynchronous events happen all the time, independent of your program. They often do not have a "completion." Normally, your program will *subscribe* to an asynchronous event stream, receive some number of *updates*, and then *unsubscribe*. Your program can treat the *subscribe* and *unsubscribe* as a "start" and "completion", but the actual event stream never really stops.

Parallel operations are best expressed using PLINQ or `Parallel`, since they have a lot of built-in support for partitioning, limited concurrency, etc. A parallel operation may easily be wrapped in an awaitable by running it from a `ThreadPool` thread (`Task.Factory.StartNew`).

Asynchronous events do not map well to asynchronous operations. One problem is that an asynchronous operation has a single result at its point of completion. Asynchronous events may have any number of updates. [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) is the natural language for dealing with asynchronous events.

There are some mappings from an Rx event stream to an asynchronous operation, but none of them are ideal for all situations. It's more natural to consume asynchronous operations by Rx, rather than the other way around. IMO, the best way of approaching this is to use asynchronous operations in your libraries and lower-level code as much as possible, and if you need Rx at some point, then use Rx from there on up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably a good example of how not to use the new async feature (that's not writing a new RSS client or Twitter app), mid-method overload points in a virtual method call. To be honest, i am not sure there is any way to create more than a single overload point per method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace AsyncText
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Derived d = new Derived();

            TaskEx.Run(() => d.DoStuff()).Wait();

            System.Console.Read();
        }
        public class Base
        {
            protected string SomeData { get; set; }

            protected async Task DeferProcessing()
            {
                await TaskEx.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1) );
                return;
            }
            public async virtual Task DoStuff() {
                Console.WriteLine("Begin Base");
                Console.WriteLine(SomeData);
                await DeferProcessing();
                Console.WriteLine("End Base");
                Console.WriteLine(SomeData);
            }
        }
        public class Derived : Base
        {
            public async override Task DoStuff()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Begin Derived");
                SomeData = "Hello";
                var x = base.DoStuff();
                SomeData = "World";
                Console.WriteLine("Mid 1 Derived");
                await x;
                Console.WriteLine("EndDerived");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output Is:

> Begin Derived
>
> Begin Base
>
> Hello
>
> Mid 1 Derived
>
> End Base
>
> World
>
> EndDerived

With certain inheritance hierarchies (namely using command pattern) i find myself wanting to do stuff like this occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UIParallelism.aspx#heading0007) about showing how to use the 'async' syntax in a non-networked scenario that involves UI and multiple actions.